# Prestashop module multilanguage form

Tags: prestashop

I am developing for prestashop 1.5 and can't find any examples of how to develop a multilanguage form(not even old documentation for prestashop 1.4). How can i achieve something like this [image]

there simply is no documentation anywhere on the internet and reverse engineering the code is too difficult at the moment.

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but you can start from there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385695/create-product-from-a-module-in-prestashop

Answer (score 0):

```
Try adding **'lang' => 'true'** in your renderForm() function in your controller like the following code

     array(
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'label' => $this->l('Text'),
    'name' => 'text',
    'lang' => true
    ),

In your class in $definition array add this line : 

     'text' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true,'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'),

Finally, add the field in **lang table** of your module or existing table
```